# How to cache a database from cloud

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, architecture, h2

I'm looking for a way to cache a large database from cloud to a host (say X) on local network. The cloud database is in Postgresql and the host X has a H2 in-memory database for fast access.

For my needs I require a subset of database from cloud to be downloaded at host X when it initializes. The subset database depends upon the specification sent by host X. For example, if host X is in network1, I want it to cache specific records and if it is in network2, I want it to cache some other records from the cloud.

The host X is unreliable and can restart anytime, so the database cache has to be build whenever the host X initiates. How can I solve this problem?

I thought about building a API in cloud to fetch the database. But since the subset database which has to be sent could be huge, I'm not sure how to implement this. Should I send a big file containing the whole subset database or send it record by record. If I send the subset database record by record, how would I keep track of what records have been sent and what not. Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Some possible solutions, depending on your problem space.  I assume by the fact that you are working on a cache, you can have out-of-date data.  I would recommend that you regularly create an export of the various subsets, and put them in a file location (S3/Block Blob/etc) that you can pull into the subscribing database on server startup.  You can decide how stale acceptable is by deciding how often to export the content.

Alternatively, if you need the dump more real-time to server-startup, I'd use the same method, but instead of it being a push, make it a pull.  Ask for the db dump, block until it's done, then have the main server respond with the dump location instead of the data itself.

Regardless of the solution, you will be in a consistent state when the client server starts up.